# link button click event not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asplinkbutton

I am working on a project where I am creating a dynamic table.Now depending upon my condition I am adding link button to table cells,but the click event of my link button is not working.I am not getting why its not working,neither its showing any error.
Following is my code

```
public void makeCalendar()
{
    tblcalendar.Rows.Clear();
    //for current month
    DateTime startingdate = StartDateOfMonth(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(monthclickedno));
    DateTime enddate = EndDateOfMonth(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(monthclickedno));
    string startingday = startingdate.DayOfWeek.ToString();
    int startingdayno = Convert.ToInt32(startingdate.DayOfWeek);
    string endday = enddate.DayOfWeek.ToString();//like saturday is 6,stating is from monday with 1 and ending is sunday with 7
    int enddayno = Convert.ToInt32(enddate.DayOfWeek);
    //for prevoius month
    DateTime enddateprevious = (EndDateOfMonth(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(monthclickedno)));
    //for next month
    DateTime startingdatenext = StartDateOfMonth(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1));
    DateTime dtstart=startingdate.AddDays(-(startingdayno+1));
    //sMonthName = "January";
    //int iMonthNo = Convert.ToDateTime("01-" + sMonthName + "-2011").Month; 
    for (int i = 0; i <7;i++)
    {
        TableRow tr = new TableRow();
        for (int j = 0; j < 7;j++ )
        {
            TableCell tc = new TableCell();
            clickablecell ctCell = new clickablecell();
            //tc.ID = idtc.ToString();
            idtc++;
            if(i==0)
            {
                tr.CssClass = "firstrow";
                tc.CssClass = "firstrowcell";
                if (j == 0)
                    tc.Text = "Sun";
                else if (j == 1)
                    tc.Text = "Mon";
                else if (j == 2)
                    tc.Text = "Tue";
                else if (j == 3)
                    tc.Text = "Wed";
                else if (j == 4)
                    tc.Text = "Thu";
                else if (j == 5)
                    tc.Text = "Fri";
                else if (j == 6)
                    tc.Text = "Sat";
                tr.Cells.Add(tc);
            }
            else{
                tc.CssClass = "othercells";
                dtstart=dtstart.AddDays(1);                   
                //if date is single digit like 1,2
                if (dtstart.ToString("dd").Substring(0, (dtstart.ToString("dd").Length)-1) == "0")
                    ctCell.Text = (dtstart.ToString("dd").Substring(1));
                else
                    ctCell.Text = (dtstart.ToString("dd"));
                ctCell.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "defColor=this.style.backgroundColor;  this.style.backgroundColor='LightGray';");
                ctCell.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.backgroundColor=defColor;");
                //ctCell.ID = k.ToString();
                k++;
                ctCell.Click += new clickablecell.ClickEventHandler(textcell_Click);
                //check for events in this date
                DataTable dtevents = checkEvents(dtstart.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"));
                if (dtevents.Rows.Count != 0)
                {
                    LinkButton lnkevent = new LinkButton();
                    //lnkevent.ClientIDMode ="Static";
                    lnkevent.ID = (i+j).ToString();
                    if (dtevents.Rows.Count == 1)
                    {
                        if (dtevents.Rows[0]["eventtype"].ToString() == "Holiday")
                        {
                            lnkevent.Text = dtevents.Rows[0]["eventtype"].ToString();
                            lnkevent.CssClass = "tcholidaytext";
                            ctCell.CssClass = "tcholidaytext";
                        }
                        else if (dtevents.Rows[0]["eventtype"].ToString() == "Event")
                        {
                            lnkevent.Text = dtevents.Rows[0]["eventtype"].ToString();
                            lnkevent.CssClass = "tceventtext";
                            ctCell.CssClass = "tceventtext";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            lnkevent.Text = dtevents.Rows[0]["eventtype"].ToString();
                            lnkevent.CssClass = "tcimpdaytext";
                            ctCell.CssClass = "tcimpdaytext";
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ctCell.CssClass = "tcmixtext";
                    }
                    //lnkevent.Attributes.Add("onClick", "test();");
                    //lnkevent.Click += lnkevent_OnClick;
                    lnkevent.Click += new EventHandler(lnkevent_OnClick);
                    ctCell.Controls.Add(lnkevent);
                }  
                tr.Cells.Add(ctCell);
            }
            tblcalendar.Rows.Add(tr);
        }
    }
}
 public void lnkevent_OnClick(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    lblmonthname.Text = "hellooo";
    txttitle.Text = "";
}
```

Comment: I think the last link button must be working properly. Can u please check?

Comment: no its not working even

Comment: Have you tried using `lnkevent.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(lnkevent_OnClick);`?

Comment: No i haven't used what it will do if I will use it,I haven;t used this event handler before,can you please elaborate a little

Comment: It simply adds an event handler for your control. I forgot to mention that you'll need to replace `EventArgs e` with `RoutedEventAgrs e` in your method definition

Comment: when I changed the event handler as you suggested,its showing error type or namespace missing

Comment: Add reference to `Presentation.Core` then import `System.Windows`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51323/discussion-between-rupinder18-and-dumisani)

Comment: i suggest that you replace all this if-then-else conditions with case-switch... your code will be more readable and easier to debug...

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you are adding a button, but not binding an event listener to it. I don't know much about how asp.net does event binding, but it sounds like that could be your problem.

Maybe this link can help?

[asp.net dynamically button with event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7713242/asp-net-dynamically-button-with-event-handler)

Comment: I am not adding a button instead adding a link button please check my code and then suggest accordingly thanx

Comment: I have read the solution provided on the above link,but that will not work for me please suggest something else